# Automate exporting species distribution maps with ArcPy by iterating through species fields in graduated symbology layer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I've got a map I've made which uses an attribute table denoting 1 (present) or 0 (absent) for the distributions of hundreds of species of insects in all Florida counties, and I'm displaying them with graduated symbols where the '0', or 'absent', symbol is just displayed invisible (color set to "no color") so only the present symbology is visible. I'm sure there's a better way to do this but the goal is to only have a dot over the counties where a species is present. I've got the map all set up, and all I have to do is just cycle through the selected attribute field to generate each species map. But I really need an automated approach due to the large amount of species/maps involved here.

I'm trying to make a script to iterate through all the fields in the symbology setting and export a PNG map for each, and so far I'm not getting anywhere with it (still VERY new to this). Attached is a map, showing the attribute table:

[image: ArcGIS Pro map]

And my hopeless attempt at a script thus far is as follows:

```
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("C:\\path\\researchProject.aprx")


## Build a list of the field value aliases for displaying in a text box on the map
featureclass = "C:\\path\\Insect species localities.csv"
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(featureclass)]
# Remove ID field from start of list
field_names.pop(0)
#print(field_names) #Confirm result


## Build a list of the expanded field names for iterating the symbology with.
## I did a join with the species CSV file to a shapefile. To set the symbology in ArcPy, 
## I need a field name which for whatever reason must have the CSV filename at the start of it. 
## This step builds a list of the fieldnames formatted with that full name (CSV name + fieldname)
m = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]
l = m.listLayers()[0]
## Prune fields that aren't needed
internal_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(l)]
del internal_names[:9]
internal_names.remove('ORIG_FID')
#print(internal_names) #Confirm result


## Create a dictionary from the two lists, to (maybe?) use for iterating over the fields.
## The idea being one is used for setting symbology, the other for listing species name -
## in a text box on the map.
dictionary = dict(zip(internal_names,field_names))
#print(dictionary) #Confirm result


## Create a variable tied to the textbox on the map to display current species name
for lyt in aprx.listLayouts():
    for elm in lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        textBox = elm


## Access the symbology in the map
## Eventually my goal is to have this part in a for loop iterating through the fieldname dictionary
sym = l.symbology
## Set the classification field. Later, will do this by iterating through the above dictionary
## For now, just hardcoding one of the species fields as a test.
sym.renderer.classificationField = "Insect_species_localities_csv_Tylospilus_acutissimus"
## Set all the symbology settings again, I guess?
sym.renderer.breakCount = 2
sym.renderer.classifcationMethod = "NaturalBreaks"
sym.renderer.minimumSymbolSize = 0 #This obviously doesn't work
sym.renderer.maximumSymbolSize = 10
## Save changes so the PNG output reflects what I set above
l.symbology = sym


## Export the map to PNG
lyt.exportToPNG(r"C:\path\Project_testmap.png", resolution=300)

del aprx
```

The problem with this script is that accessing the symbology layer seems to just disregard the settings I previously configured within ArcGIS Pro for the 'absent' class, forcing me to try and reset them in the script, where it seems (?) I can't separately define colors again for the two classes and make the '0' absent symbology invisible again. My first export had black dots of equal size over both present/absent counties, so it did at least preserve the color/size from the 'present' class, but not for 'absent'. Basically, no matter what I change, the result is always an exported map where there's dots over both 'present' and 'absent' counties, instead of only 'present'.

How can I fix this script so I can get the 'absent' counties to not display or is there a better way I should be doing this presence/absence map that would still allow for quick automation of all the needed (hundreds!) of maps?

Comment: Use data driven pages with name of butterfly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. Keep a copy of the original layer with the preferred symbology settings. Turn it off, and set a copy that is turned on for the layout.

Then use the ApplySymbologyFromLayer tool to copy the symbology and change the VALUE_FIELD to the new field. The numbers for Upper value in the symbology might change but the other settings should stay the same.

```
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
bl = m.listLayers("base layer")[0]
cl = m.listLayers("change")[0]
arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer(cl,bl,[["VALUE_FIELD","Base Field Name","New Field Name"]])
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Just in case it helps anyone else, here's the revised script using the above function: https://pastebin.com/MHt2309Z